# Apollo Client and Redux setup causes infinite render loop

Tags: redux, infinite-loop, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm trying to link up React Apollo with Redux so Apollo performs the queries and mutations, and the returned data is dispatched to the Redux store in order to distribute the data around the app.

I believe I'm close to getting it right, but for some reason the app goes into an infinite loop of Redux dispatches, and I can't figure out why.

See code below:

```
class Admin extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
      }

      render({
        adminAllTokens
      }, {}) {
        return ( /* JSX */  )
      );
    }
    }

    const AllRefreshTokens = gql `
      query {
        allUsers {
          refreshToken
          email
        }
      }
    `;

    const gqlWrapper = graphql(AllRefreshTokens, {
      props: ({
        ownProps,
        data
      }) => {
        ownProps.receivedAdminTokens(data.allUsers); //dispatch to Redux store
        return {
          ...data,
          gqladminAllTokens
        };
      }
    });

    function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
      return {
        adminAllTokens: state.auth.adminAllTokens
      };
    }

    function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
      return {
        receivedAdminTokens: tokens => {
          dispatch(adminTokensReceived(tokens));
        }
      };
    }

    const reduxWrapper = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps);
    export default compose(reduxWrapper, gqlWrapper)(Admin);
```

The `adminTokensReceived()` action is in the reducer file:

```
export const adminTokensReceived = tokens => ({
    type: 'ADMIN_TOKENS_RECEIVED',
    tokens
});
```

The GraphQL query only sends one network request, but the console is showing the `ADMIN_TOKENS_RECEIVED` action dispatching constantly and crashes the browser.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever the Apollo HOC receives new props, it causes your action to fire, which updates the store and sends new props to your Apollo HOC, which causes your action to fire...

There's a couple of different ways you could handle this. In my mind, the most straightforward would be to drop the `graphql` HOC and use `withApollo` instead. Something like:

```
compose(
  withApollo,
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
  lifecycle({
    componentDidMount() {
      const { client } = this.props
      client.query({ query: AllRefreshTokens })
        .then(({data}) => {
          receivedAdminTokens(data.allUsers)
        })
        .catch( //any error handling logic )
    }
  })
)
```

The above uses recompose's `lifecycle` but you could just as easily stick the `componentDidMount` method inside your component.

That said, it seems a little redundant to use Redux to store the results of your GraphQL queries when Apollo already does it for you.

Apollo's default behavior is to retrieve the data from the cache first, and only make a network request if the data doesn't exist (which is also why you only saw the one network call). That means any number of components inside your app could be wrapped with the same `graphql` HOC, and only the first component to be rendered would trigger a request to your GraphQL endpoint -- all other components would get their `data` from the cache.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply, I understand what you mean. I am trying to replicate what the following repo is doing: https://github.com/MacKentoch/react-redux-graphql-apollo-bootstrap-webpack-starter/blob/master/src/app/views/register/index.js - do you know why this is able to mix them both together but mine won't work? I see what you mean about Redux being kind of obsolete though.

Comment: In that example, the actions are being fired off in response to a mutation, unlike what you're trying to do here.

Comment: It doesn't look like that repo uses Redux to persist the query results, it relies on the existing cache: https://github.com/MacKentoch/react-redux-graphql-apollo-bootstrap-webpack-starter/blob/01e344471c1435881a00e0f5c525409dc45b8887/src/app/views/home/index.js#L47

Comment: Ok thanks for responding again. My final reason for wanting to include redux still was because I think it's good for setting global state on things like loading states. i.e. start loading and finished loading states, but I guess all that can be handled by Apollo too. I wonder why the repo even uses redux?